# Need to encrypt Core Data

Tags: ios, security, core-data, encryption

I am making an iOS application where all data stored in Core Data needs to be encrypted when the app is not in use. I understand that newer iOS devices (and devices running iOS 4 +) have access to hardware encryption and special protection APIs, but to my understanding, these only apply when the device is locked. There is no guarantee that users of my app will have a password lock on their devices, yet I still need to encrypt.

Also, I would prefer not to encrypt every individual core data attribute by using transformable attributes, and I understand this makes querying much more difficult. Preferably, I would like to do something like encrypt the core data file on app-close, and un-encrypt it on app-open (I know this might be slower).

Any solutions?

Comment: You can do that, give it a try and ask if you have a problem.

Comment: As for the special protection API's: encrypt the data with a data encryption key. Protect this key in turn with the special protection API's. Use a layered approach. The design of your protocol is however off topic here.